# How to use JBoss Stand alone command line Parameters while starting JBoss

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, jboss7.x

I am using the following command to start JBoss EAP 7x

`./standalone.sh –server-config=standalone-full.xml -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1 -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0`

I fail to understand the use of `-Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1 -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0`

I found following description on docs.jboss.org: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Command%20line%20parameters.html, under section **Controlling the Bind Address with -b** .I did not understand it much. If someone can explain it is simpler language.

**Question**: Putting the question simply, what would happen if I use parameters `-Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1 -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0` and how it will be different if I **DON'T** use these parameters. Even when I don't use the parameters, I am still able to start my server and use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From `standalone.sh --help`

```
-b<interface>=<value>               Set system property 
                                    jboss.bind.address.<interface> to the 
                                    given value
...

-D<name>[=<value>]                  Set a system property
```

The `-b` is essentially short for passing the system property `jboss.bind.address`, e.g. `-Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0` is the same as `-b=0.0.0.0`. This means that `-bmanagement` translates to `jboss.bind.address.management` and sets your management interface to the arguments value.

That said I don't suggest binding your management address to `0.0.0.0` unless you've got something in front of your server to protect remote access.

The `-Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1` is just passing a system property `jgroups.bind_addr` with a value of `127.0.0.1`. That is likely used as an expression somewhere in your configuration.